# AutoPostBack Interface

Tags: asp.net, properties, interface

I'm creating a set of Web User Controls which will share a common base class. The base will always contain a WebControl (either a Textbox, DropDownList, CheckBoxList, RadioButtonList, ListBox, and maybe others) and a RequiredFieldValidator. All is well, except that my abstract InputControl property (defined as type WebControl) doesn't seem to have the AutoPostBack property which I want them all to have (I assume this is because not all WebControls support AutoPostBack). I would love to put this functionality in completely in the base class and not have to define it in each child. It would look like:

```
public abstract WebControl InputControl { get; set; }
public bool AutoPostBack {
    get { return InputControl.AutoPostBack; }
    set { InputControl.AutoPostBack = value; }
}
```

But this obviously won't work because AutoPostBack is not a property of WebControl. Is there another interface that I could specify that would support this, or do I need to create my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

autopostback is not in any base class because only some controls need autopostback property. what you can do is to use generics

```
 public class MyBaseUC<T> : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public abstract T InputControl { get; set; }


    }


   public partial class WebUserControl1 : MyBaseUC<TextBox>
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InputControl.AutoPostBack = false;
        }
    }
```

Regards.